# php configuration for send mail

Tags: php, email, send

I have the following script for my php send mail, but receiving an error of "Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration."

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_Email       = "bruce@webauthorsgroup.com"; //Replace with recipient email address
    $subject        = 'IFD Derby Submission'; //Subject line for emails


    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        //exit script outputting json data
        $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'type'=>'error', 
            'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
        ));

        die($output);
    } 

    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userEmail"]))
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'input' => 'Input fields are empty!'));
        die($output);
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

    //additional php validation

    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'input' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }

    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Firstname, $user_Last, $user_website, $user_address, $user_city, $user_state, $user_zip, $user_Phone, $user_Email, $user_organization, $user_lakename, $user_lakelocation, $user_LMB, $user_SMB, $user_CP, $user_NP, $user_BC, $user_WC, $user_CF, $user_SA, $user_SE, $user_TR, $user_AS, $user_YP, $user_WP, 
$user_CU, $user_S, $user_AF, $user_species, $user_derbydate, $user_derbytime, $user_Message, $user_Phone .'  -'.$user_Firstname, $headers);

    if(!$sentMail)
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Thank you '.$user_Name .'. Your derby will be listed within 24 hours.'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

Is there anything I am missing? I am using it with this form: http://icefishingderbys.com/icefish/form/contact.html

Comment: Does your system have a mail server? Are you running on Windows?

Comment: no, it's Linux hosting and yes, I have multiple email addresses with the hosting company (godaddy)

Answer (score 0):

Build up the message body instead of sending each form field as a parameter to mail()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: I work with PHP, but I'm not a developer, so "simple" is best for me